# CollapsingToolbarLayout not working as intended

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to create a screen with a complex collapsing toolbar. This is the layout for it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".view.main.profile.ProfileFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/lighter_gradient_background">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cl_user_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_profile_picture"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_image_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_image_size"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_place"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/location"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/iv_profile_picture"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_profile_picture"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_profile_picture" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_followers"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                    android:text="321"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_profile_picture"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_profile_picture" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_followers_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                    android:text="@string/followers"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_followers"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_followers"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_followers" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_following"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                    android:text="123"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_followers"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_followers" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_following_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                    android:text="@string/following"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_following"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_following"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tv_followers_label" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_edit_profile"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_profile_button"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                    android:text="@string/edit_profile"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_following_label"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_followers_label"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_followers_label" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semibold"
            android:text="@string/username"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tl_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_layout_bottom_border"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/app_bar">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:text="@string/activity" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/interests" />

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/cl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_posts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/interests_background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_add_new_interests"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/add_interests_profile_button"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                android:text="@string/add_new_interests"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                android:id="@+id/cg_interests"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:chipSpacingVertical="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_add_new_interests" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The behavior I want to achieve is when a user presses the part of the screen where the RecyclerView is and drags it up, the toolbar should collapse. The behavior that is happening now is that when a user does the above mentioned nothing happens, but when he presses and flicks the RecyclerView, only then does the toolbar collapse. Does anyone know why this is happening? How can it be fixed?

I copied instructions from tutorials and the layout is the same. Also this was implemented in another part of the app and it works well, but that fragment has a smaller simpler header, which doesn't have nested views.

Comment: You copied instructions from tutorials? Plural? You can't just take random things, put them together and expect them to work. Read the documentation, it is straightforward.

Comment: All of the tutorials i watched had the same layout, so those weren't random things. All of the guides i looked through pointed to the same solution and same layout. In the end, disabling the nested scroll view on RV did the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After disabling the nested scroll view with `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` on the RecyclerView, the layout had the intended behavior